# Canvas Screen Scaling with script Instantiated objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can anyone explain to me why, when in the editor my instantiated shop UI looks wonderful (left) but when running on the device (right), it looks squished?, like so (please excuse the dodgy cam picture!):

[image: In Editor]
[image: Wonky]

The UI bars are prefabs, containing individual Canvas's and various UI elements. Each of the canvases is manually set to use Screen Scaling, with the reference resolution set to X: 320 Y: 480, and its set to use the Width as the basis for scaling. This has proved to work brilliantly in my previous games, but this one doesn't seem to hold. I've even manually set each of the instantiated objects' properties for scaling in the script, but still nothing.

The only thing I'm doing differently is building the UI at runtime by instantiating the UI prefabs and filling them when the shop is created.

Has anyone seen this before? Know how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

When you instantiate a prefab in code and then you add that prefab to some parent, unity ui system tries to compenstate the difference between the size of a prefab when it was created and the size it should be after canvas scaler update.

When I do something like this in my code I use this extension:

```c#
public static void SetParentAndReset(this RectTransform rect, Transform parent) {
    rect.SetParent(parent);
    rect.localScale = Vector3.one;
    rect.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
}
...
var newObj = Instantiate(prefab);
var rect = newObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
rect.SetParentAndReset(parent);
rect.localPosition = new Vector3(1f, 1f, 1f); // set the actual position
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the tip. Will try it when I get home :)

Comment: Actually what JohnPoison describes is a bug - having arbitrary position and scale is not how it was meant to be.

Comment: @Vorren - Can you elaborate?

Comment: @LokiSinclair, I suppose Vorren means that the behaviour I've described (compensating the size) is wrong and this is not what you expect when you're changing the parent or instantiating the object, so I guess we can consider this as a bug in unity gui

Comment: Ah I  see. Well, I'll give this a try and see if I can produce a decent test case for a bug submission, if this is indeed the case. Many thanks!

Comment: @JohnPoison - my meaning exactly.